# The multi-selection box in the DataGridView can select up to two rows, and cancel when the third row is selected

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

The multi-selection box in the DataGridView can select up to two rows, and cancel when the third row is selected

I was using Visual Studio 2019 before everything was working fine, but when using Visual Studio 2022 it happened. I use the multi-selection box in the DataGridView in the Winforms project to select up to two rows, and cancel when the third row is selected.

```
     private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (dataGridView1. IsCurrentCellDirty)
         {
             dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
         }
     }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         if(GetSelectRows().Count>2)
         {
             dataGridView1.Rows[e.rowindex].Cells[e.columnindex].Value = false;
         }
    }
```

There used to be a lot of freedom in terms of choice.

Comment: According to the code you provide, execute such logic. When you select the third row, the dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event fires during the selection process, committing the edit. Because the edit is committed, the dataGridView1_CellValueChanged event is fired, and since this is in the middle of a selection (that is, the third row is not fully selected), the code deselects the third row by setting its value to false. So you can only select two rows. You want to reduce the dependency on these two events appropriately according to your project needs.